# Skiena the Algorithm Design Manual - Geometric Series Clarification

Tags: algorithm

[image]

Picture taken from book.

That is an explanation of a geometric series from the book, which I do not understand. 
Constant ratio is `a` right? 
So let's take first term (just the sum function), for `n = 5`, and `constant ratio = 2`.

So we will have this: 
`2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^5 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 = 63`

No if I use the RHS, 
`a(a^n+1 - 1)/(a - 1)`. 
So it will give this: `2(2^5+1 - 1)/(2 - 1)` for `n = 5` this gives *126*.

How can they be equal ?

Also it says later on: '*when a > 1 the sum grows rapidly with each new term..*' Is he talking about space complexity ?

Because I do not get the big-theta notation. So for `n = 5` and `a = 2` it will take Big-Theta(64), 64 (2^6) steps?

Here is some ruby code:

```
n = 5
a = 2
sum = 0

for i in 0..n do
  sum = sum + a**i
end

puts sum # prints 63
```

I can see `n+1` steps.

Any help understanding this please?

Comment: This has nothing to do with algorithms or complexity, this is about geometric series as in, the limit of the sum of the terms of a geometric sequence when you let the number of terms go to infinity. If it's the math you're confused by here, this should go on math.SE

Comment: @G.Bach The maths are not confusing, I just applied a simple substitution and got different results. I was wondering what I did wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula in the book is wrong, there is an extra *a* factor (*n=0* should yield *1*, not *a*).

"The sum grows rapidly" is just about the values of the sum, it does not describe the complexity of computing it.

Comment: thanks god! thanks for that. this is like the second mistake I find in this book

Comment: @TrtTrt There are a million more: http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~skiena/algorist/book/errata